# Mulipart upload issue

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to record video and at the same time start multipart upload of this file via amazon s3 sdk. **What will happen with uploaded data if the upload does not finished?** **Will uploaded data appears on my bucket, if yes, could I play it?**

Those questions refer to those who have aver found such issue, otherwise ignore it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. S3 will do this correctly as you ask S3 to "assemble" the files in a separate call after all the parts are ready. It is at this stage, the file is made available on S3. 
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html

Since you are doing video (and I have some experience with videos), the is a pitfall. Typically video encoding softwares does modification to the beginning part of the file, when you end the recording (this is to do with the way the video file format is organized and they do this so that the progressive-download of videos are good). If this is the case, you will end up with a corrupted video on S3, since your code "had already uploaded" the initial parts. This is not the case always - varies with video format, tools used etc. So be aware of this (if not beware !)

Answer (score 2):

1. Not appear on your bucket.
2. No.